# How to configure cxf rsclient bean in Java dsl?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, cxf

I want to define cxf:rsclient in Java dsl instead of xml based dsl.
I have the following defined in Java dsl.

```
    from("direct:fromChannel")
        .split()
        .tokenizeXML("APIDataMessage").streaming()
        .unmarshal(jaxb)
        .convertBodyTo(com.testing.camel.MeasureEvent.class)
        .setHeader("Content-Type", constant("application/json"))
        .to("cxfrs://bean://toClient");
```

And I have the following for RSClient

```
@Bean
public SpringJAXRSClientFactoryBean toClient()
{
    SpringJAXRSClientFactoryBean springJAXRSClientFactoryBean = new SpringJAXRSClientFactoryBean();
    String measurementEventURL = "http://" + connectorsConfig.getHost() + 
            ":" + connectorsConfig.getPort() + "/api/measurementEvents";

    springJAXRSClientFactoryBean.setBeanId("toClient");
    springJAXRSClientFactoryBean.setAddress(measurementEventURL);
    springJAXRSClientFactoryBean.setServiceClass(com.testing.camel.MeasurementEventEndpoint.class);
    springJAXRSClientFactoryBean.setLoggingFeatureEnabled(true);
    springJAXRSClientFactoryBean.setSkipFaultLogging(true);
    springJAXRSClientFactoryBean.setProvider(jsonProvider());
    return springJAXRSClientFactoryBean;
}
```

And here is my jsonProvider definition:

```
JacksonJsonProvider jsonProvider()
{
    return new JacksonJsonProvider();
}
```

And following is the stacktrace that I see while calling this route.

### Stacktrace

```
org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfOperationException: JAXRS operation failed invoking http://0.0.0.0:8089/monnitmysqltsdb?restletMethods=POST with statusCode: 405
    at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.jaxrs.CxfRsProducer.populateCxfRsProducerException(CxfRsProducer.java:419)
    at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.jaxrs.CxfRsProducer.invokeHttpClient(CxfRsProducer.java:232)
    at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.jaxrs.CxfRsProducer.process(CxfRsProducer.java:89)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor$2.doInAsyncProducer(SendProcessor.java:169)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInAsyncProducer(ProducerCache.java:341)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:164)
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:460)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:121)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:460)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.doProcessSequential(MulticastProcessor.java:668)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.doProcessSequential(MulticastProcessor.java:596)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.process(MulticastProcessor.java:237)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Splitter.process(Splitter.java:104)
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:460)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190)
    at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:62)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:141)
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:460)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:190)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:109)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.doProcessParallel(MulticastProcessor.java:814)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.access$200(MulticastProcessor.java:84)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor$1.call(MulticastProcessor.java:314)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor$1.call(MulticastProcessor.java:299)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: The above code was working perfectly but, my bad I had some bugs in configuration class. I have checked in the code in git @ https://github.com/vivek-dhayalan/camel_cxfrs_spring_boot_java_dsl please have a loot if you wish.